# mod_wsgi where do i get it from?

Tags: mod-wsgi

i'm following this tutorial:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

and downloading my own source of mod_wsgi.

The problem is, the tutorial suggests i download the tar file i need from

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list

but all the files there are "so" files! I'm not familiar with a "so" file, but it sure isn't a tar file, at least not as the tutorial indicates. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These .so files are not source files, but the binary apache modules which enable apache to run WSGI-compliant python web applications. Note there is a specific .so file for each platform (MAC OSX and win32) and python version (it should match the version of python you have installed).

If you are on windows the easier way to install it should be getting the proper .so file and install it in your apache modules directory. On Linux you should download the source and compile it according to the README contained in the tar file, which is also on the link you provided ([mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz&can=2&q=)).

Building the module is not required if you got the binary form. Either way, after you have installed it you have to configure apache to load it, according to the instructions contained on the **Loading Module Into Apache** section of the [Quick Installation Guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide)

Comment: The label 'mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz  mod_wsgi-3.3 - Source Code Archive' and specifically 'Source Code Archive' is obviously not clear enough. ;-)

Comment: thanks for that! yeah, i didn't see the tar file initially - i was just looking for the wsgi that tied to my python version